# Best practices to modelize top layers over CNN

Tags: deep-learning, keras, computer-vision

I'm fine-tuning a InceptionResnetv2 network to get a features extractor, so I'm training a classical classifier with my data (one label/data, i'm using a softmax).

I would like to know how to choose architecture for top layers (fully connected), I read that usually Flatten -> Dense -> Dropout -> Softmax were used.

How to choose between

- Flatten/MaxPool/AvgPool
- Dense(256)/Dense(512)/Dense(1024)

is it purely empyric ?

Comment: In my experience the procedure is empiric, with the only exception of *Global Average Pooling* layers, which are usually placed deliberatly.

Answer (score 1):

Deep learning is primarily an empirical field, best practices are found through trial and error.

Since you are exploring relatively few hyperparameter combinations, they can be compared using grid-search cross-validation.